# Best way to migrate entire server?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, migration

I have a kimsufi box running Ubuntu 12.04, on this machine I have a number of websites supported by various installed packages such as apache and mysql.

I have since purchased an improved server and wish to move everything onto the new box.

What is the fastest & easiest way to migrate all of my data, including configurations etc so I can continue as normal using the new server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure why this was downvoted. Perhaps someone thought that this question was too open ended? Maybe they thought that there is no 'best' way to do this. IDK about that but I can tell you how I do this....

In the course of managing several web servers you'll quickly become a master of installing LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySql, PHP). I would simply backup you apache website configuration files ( not everything just the file(s) which defines your web server directory structure; in Ubuntu /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/* ).

Also, backup all of the website files you have. You'll also want to backup your databases. The proper way to do this depends on the DBMS you use. If you're using MySQL use mysqldump ( http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump ) which is almost certainly going to already be on your old server.

Then on your new box do a basic lamp installation: http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_lamp_for_newbies

Once you have that running put your website files and the configuration files in place. You'll need to reconfigure your DB users as well.

This may sound like a lot of work at first but it really isn't. After you do this a few times you'll be able to finish all of this in about 15 minutes without issue.

Lastly, you'll need to also update your DNS entries to point to the new server.

EDIT: Also, if you use SSL on your sites then you'll want to backup the files you installed when you installed that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pull out the disks from the old server and put them in the new server or clone them with clonezilla?

Comment: I don't have physical access to the server, I rent it and have SSH/telnet access.